# How to use customized .conf file instead of ssl.conf in centos7 httpd

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl

I have a centos 7 server.

For apache, I dont want to use `ssl.conf` and want to use my own customized files `pyramid.conf` and `pylons.conf` and `django.conf` etc.

So for each python framework, I created separate conf file and everything works fine until yesterday. When automatic security updates were applied to system. And that made `ssl.conf magically appear under /etc/hhtpd/conf.d`

Is there any way I can get rid of ssl.conf .

Answer (score 2):

I guess I can paraphrase the advice given in the `welcome.conf` file (that is responsible for the "1,2,3, testing" page): the package manager has no way of knowing that the file was once there and you intentionally deleted it and do not want it to come back. It is marked as a configuration file, though, so if you have changed its contents, the package manager will not overwrite it with a new `ssl.conf` (putting the new file into `ssl.conf.rpmnew` instead).

What this means for your problem is: just comment out all the lines in `ssl.conf`, if you think you want them for future reference, or do

```
rm /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf; touch /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

to replace it with an empty file. Either way, it won't influence the configuration state of your server anymore, and `rpm` will see that you've changed the file, so it won't touch it.

Comment: Sound advice of leaving the `ssl.conf` file in place. I was already bitten by this in the past. +1